# Specific ORDER BY clause in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

My MySQL database contains Multiple products stored in 4 categories. All informations are in the same table :

```
id - name - description - price - category
```

I'am trying to list them in this order. I wonder do this only by MySQL request if possible.

```
Cat1 : product-name-with-lower-price1
Cat2 : product-name-with-lower-price1
Cat3 : product-name-with-lower-price1
Cat4 : product-name-with-lower-price1

Cat1 : product-name-with-lower-price2
Cat2 : product-name-with-lower-price2
Cat3 : product-name-with-lower-price2
Cat4 : product-name-with-lower-price2

Cat1 : product-name-with-lower-price3
Cat2 : product-name-with-lower-price3
Cat3 : product-name-with-lower-price3
Cat4 : product-name-with-lower-price3
```

etc...

I'm sorry to not give any source code I tested because every thing I tried don't work. I think to use the MySQL Order By clause but I don't know how.

Many thx

EDIT :

Products are listed by lower price. After extract lower price of each Cat, we Order by price ASC. Then extract next lower-price of each cat and order by price ASC and so on...

So it could look like this :

```
Cars : Aygo 8000$
Moto : Suzuki 8200$
Bus : Renault 8700$
Truck : Peugeot 9000$

Cars : Toyota 9300$
Bus  :  Renault 9400$
Truck : DMG 9600$
Moto : Harley 14000$


Bus : Mercedes 12000$
Moto : BMW : 18000$
Cars : Mercedes 11000$
Truck : Renault 10000$
```

Comment: Show us what SQL statements you have tested so far.

Comment: have you only 4 categories ? or more ?

Comment: @Begueradj For now I Have only 4. But in future I will advise :)

Comment: Which column you need to order and how asc or desc?

Comment: @S.M.Mohiuddin Orderby By product Price. Yes you are right : Categories can be in diferent order if lower-price-1 is in category 3 bye example. I edit my question

Comment: categories can be in any order ? only the order of price interests you ?

Comment: @Begueradj Yes but I need only one product of each cat orderered by price (not cat) and take another group of prices

Comment: `order by name , price` this should do the job

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty hmmm no sry this order my products 1st by alphabetical order

Comment: so how you want the order please add the desire result-set into the question. May be create a fiddle on http://sqlfiddle.com with some sample data.

Comment: @Strawberry So now we can downvote because of [jealousy]... Seriously ?

Comment: We can down vote for reasons as arbitrary as upvoting, but I'm with @AbhikChakraborty on this one

Comment: So I'll keep it in my mind for futur downvote... [Arbitrary] and [jealousy] :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intended to be an improvement on Raina's approach.  There are two issues with the approach.  The first is the `order by` in the subquery.  There is no guarantee that an order by in a subquery will produce results in the same order (it usually works in practice in MySQL, but you should not rely on the behavior).  The second is having multiple variable assignments in the `select`.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of assignments.

A safer way of write this is:

```
SELECT id, price, category 
FROM (SELECT (@rownum := IF(@cat = t.category, @rownum + 1, 
                            IF(@cat := t.category, 1, 1) 
                           )
             )criteria,
             t.* 
      FROM Table1 t
      ORDER BY category, price
     ) tt
ORDER BY tt.criteria, tt.category;
```

Comment: Upvoted, thank you for these notes. While I'm not sure I understand how this approach is different in relation to the first issue you mentioned (order by in the nested query), this indeed seems to be a more stable in relation to the second one (order of assignments). Overall I think it'd be great to re-investigate this; the [most comprehensive article about ordering](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/15/advanced-mysql-user-variable-techniques/) seems to be a bit old.

Comment: @raina77ow . . . The restriction on ordering in subqueries is an ANSI standard restriction and I have not (yet) found a reference in MySQL documentation that explicitly says you can depend on `order by` in a subquery without a limit clause.  This is a big issue in parallelized databases, such as MariaDB (which is derived from MySQL).  The second is a real problem, under some circumstances, variables are actually evaluated in a different order.

Comment: Ah, now I see (or so I think): the expressions in `SELECT` will be applied after the rows are ordered anyway, so nested query wasn't actually necessary. Thanks again. )

Comment: One last question though: I've noticed the word 'safer', but is this approach really, well, bulletproof? In other words, can we be sure that second `IF`'s clause will never be executed before the first one's? It seems reasonable. )

Comment: @raina77ow . . . Yes.  I'm pretty sure `if` guarantees order of evaluation.  It *is* non-standard SQL, so this could be replaced with a `case`, which does have that guarantee.  The documentation (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) is not 100% clear on this point.  One would have to assume that "returns" means "evaluates and returns" (not unreasonable, but not explicit).

Comment: I see. For the sake of completeness, I've added `CASE` approach to my answer, showing how `FIELD` function can be used to set up a specific order of categories as well.

Comment: Many thanks @GordonLinoff for improved answer. Your are awesome too ! Accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach:

```
SELECT id, price, category 
  FROM (
      SELECT @rownum := 
        (CASE
          WHEN @cat = t.category THEN @rownum + 1
          ELSE (@cat := t.category) IS NOT NULL
          END) criteria,
        t.* 
      FROM Table1 t
      ORDER BY category, price
  ) tt
ORDER BY tt.criteria, 
  FIELD(tt.category, 'Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Cat3');
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1dc32/23). `FIELD` function is used to set up a specific ordering of categories; if you're ok with them sorted in alphabetical order, you can replace that just with `ORDER BY tt.criteria, tt.category`.

Comment: Thx for this approach, I was quite sure I need a trick like that. But this seems to not work. This order By categories in 1st, list all products in category oredered by prices and then go to next category and list all products etc. The cycle I expect is not respected :( You can see it in your Fiddle : The 2 1st products are form cat A. I use approach and trying to make this working...

Comment: _stroke_The 2 1st products are form cat A._stroke_ 
Sorry I was looking in the wrong place. I test your new code and do a fiddle if needed. Thx @raina77ow

Comment: @raina77ow . . . You should see the answer I posted.

Comment: @MrSo I'd recommend accepting @GordonLinoff answer instead, as he's shown two very important issues in this answer; one I was actually aware of (but somehow thought it's not applicable because of `IF`; now I don't think so), and another that I wasn't aware at all. Without you unaccepting my answer I won't be able to remove it. )

Comment: OK but you still are awesome :) I considere your request for the issues even if it seems to work well for my purposes.